# Switching div content with another div content position

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

i wonder if there is a way of switching position of draggable div content with position of drop div content. I have 6 draggable divs wich has img and p tags in. What i need is to switch position when i drag over another div. Thanks

First should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/3CM2M/

after switch: http://jsfiddle.net/3CM2M/1/

```
$(dropObjects).draggable({ 
        axis: "x", 
        zIndex: 100});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sortable` feature of jQuery UI with `draggable`.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ connectToSortable: "#my-sortable" });
```

Here is [the working example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) and the [corresponding documentation (connectToSortable)](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable) in jQuery UI's official website.

And here is the detailed information about:

- [`Sortable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)
- [`Draggable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable)

Comment: Thx for ur reply, im gonna check